# Controlling the Back Button after Navigation Punchout

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I have been trying to control the back button behavior on how far back it goes to the capsule after leaving the navigation punchout command. Such as, after pressing the back button on the website that was punchout, it takes me back two layout screens, rather than one.

The model of my capsule goes in this flow:

(Vocal input) -> **Object List** (After vocal input) -> **Object Page** (After selecting an object) -> **Website Link Punchout** (After an on-click event of the object page)

**Website Link Punchout:**

```
result-view {
  match : ObjectWebsite (this) {
    min(Required) max (One)
  }

  render {

  }

  app-launch {
    payload-uri("object website link")
  }
}
```

The expected result, while being on the website page, is to return to the **object page**, not to the **object list page**.

The output results in returning to the **object list page** after I press back button to exit the website link.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for raising this question. The scenario you have mentioned would be a bug, pending verification on our end. Please open a ticket with Developer Support to be notified when this bug is fixed/closed.